# Cannot associate an action on a primefaces lazy loading table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've been trying to make use of primefaces lazy loading datatable. Without the lazy loading, the method delete(trans) gets called but not same with the lazy. Please, can someone tell me why the delete(trans) is never called when clicked. I've been on it all day (I tried with primefaces 4.x and 5.x)

```
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{transactionView.transactions}" var="trans"
                     paginator="true" rows="10"
                     paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" lazy="true">
            <p:column headerText="#{messages.trans_date}" width="100">
                <h:outputText value="#{trans.transDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{messages.date_pattern2}"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="#{messages.description}">
                <h:outputText value="#{trans.description}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandLink value="X" style="color: red" update="@form" ajax="true"
                               action="#{transactionView.delete(trans)}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Lazy basically has got nothing to do with `<p/h:commandXxx action(Listener)="#{...}"/>`. As can be got impression from name itself, you are utterly trying to delete a specific row from the said `<p:dataTable>`. Selected row(s) of a `<p:dataTable>` can be supplied to an associated backing bean several ways round other than just a parameterized action(Listener) method as also mentioned on the showcase.

Comment: @Tiny Its not only about the delete operation i want to do on the table but any other method i add, like trying to edit

Comment: OK I had in my application, basically very rare chances (or possibly no chances at all) to pass a model object directly using a parameterized getter while performing basic CRUD operations using a data table - `<p:dataTable>`. A basic [edit/update](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) operation, for example, can easily be performed using `<p:rowEditor/>`. The feature is provided out of the box by the library itself. [This](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/contextMenu.xhtml) is for a delete operation. The insert operation can be handled separately.

Comment: Thanks for the response but you know, its easier to do it like in the question as its possible without adding lazy="true". However, I will look at the showcase and work with that

Comment: Don't you already find those showcase examples as easy as your current snippet? :)